# Install PHP 5.4 on Debian 6 from dotdeb

Tags: php, debian

On [dotdeb.org](https://www.dotdeb.org/) it is said:

> **On February 18th 2015, the PHP group released PHP 5.4.38.**
>
> The corresponding packages are now available on Dotdeb :
>
> for Debian 7 “Wheezy” and Debian 6 “Squeeze”, on both amd64 and i386
>   architectures.

That is cool, but I have added them to sources list, updated package list with `apt-get update`, and made `apt-get upgrade`... but PHP only updated to `5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0`

Any idea why and how to fix it? There is totally no contact with them.

My sources.list:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
```

Commands and output:

```
apt-get update
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze Release.gpg
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze/all Translation-en_US
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 Release.gpg
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54/all Translation-en_US
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze Release
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 Release
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze/all Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze/all Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54/all Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54/all Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze/all Packages
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze/all Sources
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54/all Packages
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54/all Sources
Reading package lists... Done

apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-client php-pear php5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-imagick php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-sqlite
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

Comment: for general questions about computing, please consider asking on [su] or (more specific) on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing the existing PHP packages before you install the new version from the dotdeb.

If that doesn't work you can instruct the apt to install the php from the specific repository like it this described here:

[Install package from specific repo](https://superuser.com/questions/124174/how-can-i-specify-the-repository-from-which-a-package-will-be-installed-emacs)